# WordPress jQuery plugin not defined and works when I logged out

Tags: jquery, wordpress, undefined, uncaught-exception

I have a plugin. The strange thing is it works only when I am logged in. If I visit as a guest there are many errors in the console: http://prntscr.com/ot1gde

This is how I called/included the JS files of the plugin:

https://github.com/thehung2224/jquery-issue/blob/master/scripts.php

This is Js codes https://github.com/thehung2224/jquery-issue/blob/master/functions.js

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I assume there is actually some logic returned to `WVC` from the IIFE, and that you're just omitted it from the question...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  I updated JS code, hope you can check. It drives me crazy :(